# Странное поведение при наследовании от ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter в netty

Tags: java, ооп, netty

Есть класс наследуемый от `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`, где переопределяю нужные методы. Например, `channelUnregistered`:

```
public abstract class HttpServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super. channelUnregistered(ctx);
        // something doing here
    }
    [...]
}
```

Если использую этот класс, то `channelUnregistered` срабатывает, когда закрывается соединение с клиентом.

Но если я от него унаследуюсь:

```
public abstract class HttpsServerHandler extends HttpServerHandler {

}
```

При использовании этого класс `channelUnregistered` никогда не срабатывает. Но если переопределю этот метод и просто вызову метод из `super` класса, то всё работает:

```
public abstract class HttpsServerHandler extends HttpServerHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super. channelUnregistered(ctx);
    }
}
```

Мой мозг отказывается работать. В базовом классе есть этот метод, если я его не переопределяю в дочернем, то должен вызваться метод базового класса. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Метод не обязан вызываться, если не вызывается явно вручную, или из конструктора. Проверьте, вызовется ли метод  `channelUnregistered` (родительского класса), если его не переопределить в `HttpServerHandler`.

Comment: @LEQADA либо он вызывается https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/43ebbc3fa065155fa67732b0cbd7c12843b0f3f7/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java#L118

Comment: *библиотекой он вызывается

Comment: @Suvitruf настолько же банальный вопрос для того, чтобы убедиться, что вы уже все испробовали: в дебаггере на этой точке в `next.invoker()` оказывается то, что вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 1):

У netty есть класс ServerBootstrap, которому в настройках необходимо задать конфигурацию сервера. Одна из необходимых настроек вызывается функцией childHandler(), в которую передается объект типа ChannelHandler, обязанный контролировать запросы канала. Таким образом для каждого нового соединения создается объект ChannelHandler, который вы привязали ранее при помощи childHandler(). Однако ваши классы объявлены абстрактными и, очевидно, их экземпляры нигде не создаются. Если Вы "привяжете" HttpsServerHandler к своему серверу, то все должно работать.